# Valid identifier characters in Scala

Tags: scala, operators

One thing I find quite confusing is knowing which characters and combinations I can use in method and variable names. For instance

```
val #^ = 1 // legal
val #  = 1 // illegal
val +  = 1 // legal
val &+ = 1 // legal
val &2 = 1 // illegal
val £2 = 1 // legal
val ¬  = 1 // legal
```

As I understand it, there is a distinction between *alphanumeric identifiers* and *operator identifiers*. You can mix an match one or the other but not both, unless separated by an underscore (a *mixed identifier*).

From *Programming in Scala* section 6.10,

> An operator identifier consists of one or more operator characters.
>   Operator characters are printable ASCII characters such as +, :, ?, ~
>   or #.
>
> More precisely, an operator character belongs to the Unicode set
>   of mathematical symbols(Sm) or other symbols(So), or to the 7-bit
>   ASCII characters that are not letters, digits, parentheses, square
>   brackets, curly braces, single or double quote, or an underscore,
>   period, semi-colon, comma, or back tick character.

So we are excluded from using `()[]{}'"_.;,` and `

I looked up Unicode mathematical symbols on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode), but the ones I found didn't include `+`, `:`, `?` etc. Is there a definitive list somewhere of what the operator characters are?

Also, any ideas why Unicode mathematical operators (rather than symbols) do not count as operators?

Comment: I particularly miss ². Scala kind of promises one can make code that uses clever variable (and method) names. But you cannot give a value to a variable x². Illegal character.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Working from the [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) syntax in the specification:

```
upper ::= ‘A’ | ... | ‘Z’ | ‘$’ | ‘_’ and Unicode category Lu
lower ::= ‘a’ | ... | ‘z’ and Unicode category Ll
letter ::= upper | lower and Unicode categories Lo, Lt, Nl
digit ::= ‘0’ | ... | ‘9’
opchar ::= “all other characters in \u0020-007F and Unicode
            categories Sm, So except parentheses ([]) and periods”
```

But also taking into account the very beginning on Lexical Syntax that defines:

```
Parentheses ‘(’ | ‘)’ | ‘[’ | ‘]’ | ‘{’ | ‘}’.
Delimiter characters ‘‘’ | ‘’’ | ‘"’ | ‘.’ | ‘;’ | ‘,’
```

Here is what I come up with. Working by elimination in the range `\u0020-007F`, eliminating letters, digits, parentheses and delimiters, we have for `opchar`... (drum roll):

**`! # % & * + - / : < = > ? @ \ ^ | ~`** 
and also [`Sm`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm) and [`So`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/list.htm) - except for parentheses and periods.

In summary, here are some valid examples that highlights all cases—watch out for `\` in the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop); I had to escape as `\\`:

```
val !#%&*+-/:<=>?@\^|~ = 1 // All simple opchars
val simpleName = 1
val withDigitsAndUnderscores_ab_12_ab12 = 1
val wordEndingInOpChars_!#%&*+-/:<=>?@\^|~ = 1
val !^©® = 1 // opchars and symbols
val abcαβγ_!^©® = 1 // Mixing Unicode letters and symbols
```

---

<sup>Note 1:</sup>

I found this Unicode [category index](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) to figure out `Lu, Ll, Lo, Lt, Nl`:

- Lu (uppercase letters)
- Ll (lowercase letters)
- Lo (other letters)
- Lt (titlecase)
- Nl (letter numbers like roman numerals)
- Sm (symbol math)
- So (symbol other)

<sup>Note 2:</sup>

```
val #^ = 1 // legal   - two opchars
val #  = 1 // illegal - reserved word like class or => or @
val +  = 1 // legal   - opchar
val &+ = 1 // legal   - two opchars
val &2 = 1 // illegal - opchar and letter do not mix arbitrarily
val £2 = 1 // working - £ is part of Sc (Symbol currency) - undefined by spec
val ¬  = 1 // legal   - part of Sm
```

<sup>Note 3:</sup>

Other operator-looking things that are reserved words: **`_ : = => <- <: <% >: # @`** and also `\u21D2` ⇒ and `\u2190` ←

Comment: Thanks. Also, as the spec says, we are limited to Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane characters, i.e. 2-byte characters up \ufffd. Thus from `So`, \u262f the Yin Yang operator is legal, but \u1f360 the Roasted Sweet Potato operator is not supported (it's interpreted as \u1f36 + '0').

Comment: In Scala 2.9, `£` is now reported as an `illegal character` (presumably the correct behavior wrt the spec).

Comment: The § character is also not valid. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 10):

[The language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf). gives the rule in Chapter 1, lexical syntax (on page 3):

> 1. Operator characters. These consist of all printable ASCII
>      characters \u0020-\u007F. which are in none of the sets above,
>      mathematical sym- bols(Sm) and other symbols(So).

This is basically the same as your extract of Programming in Programming in Scala. `+` is not an Unicode mathematical symbol, but it is definitely an [ASCII printable character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange#ASCII_printable_characters) not listed above (not a letter, including _ or $, a digit, a paranthesis, a delimiter).

In your list:

1. # is illegal not because the character is not an operator character
   (#^ is legal), but because it is a reserved word (on page 4), for type projection.
2. &2 is illegal because you mix an operator character & and a non-operator character, digit 2
3. £2 is legal because £ is not an operator character: it is not a seven bit ASCII, but 8 bit extended ASCII. It is not nice, as `$` is not one either (it is considered a letter).

Comment: The "mathematical sym- bols(Sm) and other symbols(So)" is the object of "consist of" or "in none of"?

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks to escape limitations and use Unicode symbols:

```
val `r→f` = 150
println(`r→f`)
```