# What does a "?" symbol (question mark) mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

I meet some scala code with "?" but do not know what it mean in scala, could anyone explain it to me ? Thanks.

And here's one example

```
 def getJobId(conf: Configuration): String =
    ?(conf.get("scoobi.jobid")).getOrElse(sys.error("Scoobi job id not set."))
```

Comment: Can you give an example? The "?" could be part of a method name, class name, or something else. It's not a standard operator in Scala.

Comment: `val lovely_? = isItAGoodDay()` <-- like that?

Comment: is it just me or is the "?" helper method in this case utterly pointless? The same result, with fewer characters and, IMHO, more clarity, is obtained with standard, conf.get("foo") getOrElse sys.error("bar")

Comment: @virtualeyes `Option.apply(x)` converts `null` to `None`. So If `conf.get("foo")` doesn't return an `Option`, but might return `null`, then this is done to convert the possible `null` to `None` (see Christian's answer).

Comment: Assumed the get in this case was on an Option, but looking again, not the case. "import Option.{apply => ?}" is, btw, really quite awesome ;-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For me it looks like the apply method of Option. Is there somewhere the following import statement in the code:

```
import Option.{apply => ?}
```

This means **apply** is imported as **?**. From the doc of Option.apply:

> An Option factory which creates Some(x) if the argument is not null,
>   and None if it is null.

The whole statement means then:

> if conf.get("scoobi.jobid") is not equal null, assign this string,
>   otherwise assign the string sys.error("Scoobi job id not set.")
>   returns

Comment: Thanks, you are right. There's an import statement ahead "import Option.{apply => ?}"

Answer (score 8):

It's just a legal character, just like "abcd..."

```
scala> def ?(i: Int) = i > 2
$qmark: (i: Int)Boolean

scala> val a_? = ?(3)
a_?: Boolean = true
```

**UPD:** See [Valid identifier characters in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656937/valid-identifier-characters-in-scala/7657692#7657692) , [Scala method and values names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629478/scala-method-and-values-names)

**UPD2:** In the example "?" could be function, method of `this` or just some object with `apply` method. It probably returns `Option[String]`.