# Asterisk in val name using Scala

Tags: scala

Just saw an example that looks like the following:

`val b_* = grater[Book].asObject(dbo)`

What is the significance of the asterisk in `b_*` here? What's the name for it in Scala and what affect does it have on the outcome of `b_`?

Comment: it doesn't have any effect, it's just part of the variable name `b_*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asterisk is valid in scala variable and value names, as are many other characters that are not allowed in in identifier names in Java or other C-like languages.  See [Valid identifier characters in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656937/valid-identifier-characters-in-scala)  for more info.

However, just because it can be done doesn't mean it should be done. To my eye, it's not obvious at all what this value represents.

Comment: it's a beaten-up face ;)