# Scala: Option[T] as ?[T] (or even T?)

Tags: scala

i tried

```
type ?[_] = Option[_]

def f(x: ?[Int]) = for (y <- x) yield y
```

(but i don't know what i am doing.)

insofar as types are just objects, i should be able to define a postix operator (i.e. zero arity method) for use in type signatures (i think). it might need a space like

```
def f(x: Int ?) = for (y <- x) yield y
```

scala makes it easy to use the Option type with matching and polymorphism, avoid null. but, most classes are (nullable) vars and java often returns vars. using classes and calling java are two of scala's selling points. an easy-to-write and easy-to-read syntax would support Options even more strongly.

1. what are all the things that scala does with "?" that make its parsing special.
2. ideally, one could write

   def f(x: Int?) = for (y <- x) yield y

like other languages. can we do this in scala (without a macro)?

Comment: I know this is not what ypu want, but you can do something like this `type \`Int?\` = Option[Int]` ... and then `def f(x: \`Int?\`) = for (y <- x) yield y`

Comment: i'd rather not use a backtick variable, and more importantly, it won't work with any type either.

Answer (score 6):

First, types are not objects. In fact, Scala has exactly two namespaces: values and types. They are very different things, and play by very different rules.

The postfix idea is kind of nice, actually, but it is not possible. There's an infix notation for types, though.

Now, to what you wrote:

```
type ?[_] = Option[_]
```

Each underscore has a different meaning. The underscore in `?[_]` means `?` is higher-kinded, but you don't care what it's type parameter is. The underscore in `Option[_]` means `Option` is an existential type. So when you write `x: ?[Int]`, Scala will convert it to `x: Option[t] { forSome type t }`. This means that not only you don't get the `Int`, but the type parameter of `Option` is unknowable (you just know it exists).

However, it *does* compile:

```
scala> def f(x: ?[Int]) = for (y <- x) yield y
f: (x: ?[Int])Option[Any]
```

Which version of Scala did you use? 2.11? A co-worker of mine has already found some type inference regressions on 2.11, so that could be it.

The proper way to write the type alias would be this:

```
type ?[+A] = Option[A]
```

Not only we pass the type parameter along (it *is* a parameter, after all!), but we need to specify co-variance for it to act just `Option` (which is co-variant itself).

Now, as to your two questions, Scala has absolutely no special treatment of `?`. And, no, you can't do this. This `?` is not exactly widespread among languages either, and in all of them that support it, it is built in the language, and not something externally defined.

Besides, it's kind of a joke that, when interface with Java, typing out `Option` would be a problem -- not with the average identifier size in Java!

Comment: I think you're correct about variance (thx), but still `val x: ?[X] = null.asInstanceOf[?[Y]]` is OK for invariant version, `Y extends X`. Am I missing something or is that the subject of those HK variance issues I don't understand? `Pair` et al are annotated.

Comment: @som-snytt Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: i mean, if you renamed some java methods in the import or used scala only, it would save typing. but that's not really the point. the point is that it looks "Optiony" which makes it feel more optional when you read it.

Comment: (i was using scala 2.10.3 and it did compile after all. my bad.)

Comment: if scala doesn't treat `?` specially, why does the type alias output "$qmark" and why won't `val x? = Some(1)` compile? (i'm using the default namespace i.e. `?` returns `not found`).

Comment: in fact it does, i've found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656937/valid-identifier-characters-in-scala/7657692

one answer says it's illegal because "illegal because you mix an operator character and a non-operator character". without an underscore.

Comment: i assume this is to let operator methods be right behind variables, and avoid `val x? = 1` change the lexing of `x?` with some `def ?() = ...`. personally, i'd be ok with mandatory whitespace (or a dot) after operators.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Added the code sample to my answer. Someday soon I'll study it, but maybe you can tell me off the cuff why it compiles. The type alias appears to inherit (so to speak) the variance of the RHS.

Comment: @samboosalis The `$qmark` is a generic name translation; similarly, colon `:` becomes `$colon`; all such operators handled that way. For a given identifier, you need an underscore between alphas and opchars, like `abc_?`. There's a recent question about that. But you want a separate `?` identifier. `val x?` makes no sense, like

Comment: ...like `val x Int`, which lacks a colon.

Answer (score 4):

You intended to get an `Option[Int]` out:

```
scala> type ?[A] = Option[A]
defined type alias $qmark

scala> def f(x: ?[Int]) = for (y <- x) yield y + 1
f: (x: ?[Int])Option[Int]
```

and it does compile anyway.

You could maybe

```
scala> type ?[A,_] = Option[A]
defined type alias $qmark

scala> def f(x: Int ? _) = for (y <- x) yield y + 1
f: (x: ?[Int, _])Option[Int]
```

or similar.

```
scala> def f(x: Int ?_) = for (y <- x) yield y + 1
f: (x: ?[Int, _])Option[Int]
```

looks more postfixy.

P.S. Still curious whether variance annotation on type alias is required or merely advisable.

```
scala> type ?[A] = Option[A]
defined type alias $qmark

scala> trait X ; trait Y extends X ; trait Z extends X
defined trait X
defined trait Y
defined trait Z

scala> val x: ?[X] = null.asInstanceOf[?[Y]]  // why is this OK?
x: ?[X] = null

scala> class C[A]
defined class C

scala> val c: C[X] = null.asInstanceOf[C[Y]]  // like this is not OK
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : C[Y]
 required: C[X]
Note: Y <: X, but class C is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
       val c: C[X] = null.asInstanceOf[C[Y]]
                                      ^
```

Maybe compare SI-8522 and related issues.

Comment: could you please explain a bit about type ?[A,_] = Option[A]? what is _ for? how does this make x: Int ? _ to an Option[Int]? thanks.

Comment: Placeholder `_` for type params is described in 4.4 http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html  where here it allows infix notation (in lieu of postfix). Actually, I just noticed that the space isn't needed, see edit.

Comment: Ah ah, I'm still pondering if I would actually use it, but I like the wildcard hack :)

Comment: By the way, you can even remove the leading space, as in `Int?_`

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles Right, I misread the OP, I thought the space was desirable. I tend to read the OP code and skip the OP text, ;tldr etc.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about the variance thing. I thought it was required, but a type alias is really an alias, so it may make sense that variance does not apply to it. OTOH, if I declare, say, `type JList[+A] = java.util.List[A]`, I get a variance error, so it clearly does pay attention to variance annotations on types.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider a renaming import. When you create a type alias you only rename a type. When you rename a symbol during import you include all referents of that name, both type and value.

To wit:

```
scala> import scala.{Option => ?}
import scala.{Option=>$qmark}

scala> val oi1: ?[Int] = Some(1)
oi1: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> def mi1(oi: ?[Int]): Int = oi.getOrElse(-1)
mi1: (oi: Option[Int])Int

scala> mi1(None)
res1: Int = -1

scala> mi1(?(1))
res2: Int = 1
```

Compare with this:

```
scala> type ?[A] = Option[A]

scala> def mi1(oi: ?[Int]): Int = oi.getOrElse(-1)
mi1: (oi: ?[Int])Int

scala> mi1(?(1))
<console>:10: error: not found: value ?
              mi1(?(1))
                  ^
```