# Unable to use Euro currency symbol (€) as method name

Tags: scala

I want to write some code for currency stuff, so I try to use € for some nice postfix notation.

But I get this compiler error

```
Error:(46, 9) illegal character '\u20ac'
def € = EUR
    ^
```

Am I doing something wrong? Cos $ works fine and is a currency symbol as well.

Comment: `$` is allowed in Scala variable names, while most Unicode characters aren't. Check out this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656937/valid-identifier-characters-in-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euro symbol is not valid identifier, but you may use it with back-ticks:

```
scala> def € = 10
 error: illegal character '\u20ac'
   def € = 10
       ^

scala> def `€` = 10
€: Int
```

Comment: But if I want to use it as a postfix operator, I have to write 10 '€' what makes this solution not suitable for my case. But in terms of what I asked +1